# Get Call duration during calls programatically?

Tags: android

I am creating an application which can access phone state and will be able to end outgoing call according to certain contraints. I am able to achieve that using:

```
if (!intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"))
                return;
            else
            {

               String time = finalprefs.getString("timedelay","0");
               System.out.println("TIME - "+time);
                number = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
                WhitelistDAO whiteListDao = new WhitelistDAO(context);
                List<Whitelist> whiteList = whiteListDao.getAllWhitelist();
                if(number != null) {
                    number =  lastten(number);
                    Log.e("CALLED NUMBER", "NUM - " + number);
                    Log.e("BLOCKED NUMBER", "BLLACK - " + new Whitelist(number).toString());
                    // Check, whether this is a member of "Black listed" phone numbers stored in the database
                    if (whiteList.contains(new Whitelist(number))) {
                        Log.e("Call","Allowed");
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Success",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"This call is not allowed by your administration! Contact Karthik",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        disconnectPhoneItelephony(context);

                        return;
                    }
                }
```

**But right now i want to disconnect the outgoing call after 10 min if connected!** I searched for this and i didn't get any proper solution! Most of its tells that its not possible to get the call duration on call! So is there any workaround solution?

Please Help!

Comment: to be clear, you want to timeout a call after 10 min?

Comment: @GalYedidovich. yes exactly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you want to time your call and end it after 10 min.

so i'd recommend starting a timer to time 10 min of conversation, then using a handler, check if the same call is still going: if it does -> end it

in Java:

```
//call this method when call is starting
void startTimer() {
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {//this method will execute after 10 minutes
            //check if call is still on going
            //if so - write the logic to end call here
        }
    }, 1000 * 60 * 10); //10 min in milli-seconds
}
```

in Kotlin:

```
//call this method when call is starting
private fun startTimer() {
    Handler().postDelayed({ //this method will execute after 10 minutes
        //check if call is still on going
        //if so - write the logic to end call here
    }, 1000 * 60 * 10) //10 min in milli-seconds
}
```

Comment: Can you share a sample code to it! I am beginner in android!

Comment: yeah, i'll create one now ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code i also add permission for call log..

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final int REQUEST_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE = 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if (!checkPermissions()) {
        requestPermissions();
    } else {

        getCallDetails();
    }

}

private void getCallDetails() {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    Uri contacts = CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI;
    Cursor managedCursor = this.getContentResolver().query(contacts, null, null, null, null);
    int number = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER);
    int type = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE);
    int date = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DATE);
    int duration = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DURATION);
    sb.append("Call Details :");
    while (managedCursor.moveToNext()) {

        HashMap rowDataCall = new HashMap<String, String>();

        String phNumber = managedCursor.getString(number);
        String callType = managedCursor.getString(type);
        String callDate = managedCursor.getString(date);
        String callDayTime = new Date(Long.valueOf(callDate)).toString();
        // long timestamp = convertDateToTimestamp(callDayTime);
        String callDuration = managedCursor.getString(duration);
        String dir = null;
        int dircode = Integer.parseInt(callType);
        switch (dircode) {
            case CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE:
                dir = "OUTGOING";
                break;

            case CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE:
                dir = "INCOMING";
                break;

            case CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE:
                dir = "MISSED";
                break;
        }
        sb.append("\nPhone Number:--- " + phNumber + " \nCall Type:--- " + dir + " \nCall Date:--- " + callDayTime + " \nCall duration in sec :--- " + callDuration);
        sb.append("\n----------------------------------");


    }
    managedCursor.close();
    System.out.println(sb);
}

/**
 * this method request to permission asked.
 */
private void requestPermissions() {
    boolean shouldProvideRationale =
            ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                    Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG);

    if (shouldProvideRationale) {
    } else {
        Log.i("Error", "Requesting permission");
        // previously and checked "Never ask again".
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG},
                REQUEST_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
}

/**
 * this method check permission and return current state of permission need.
 */
private boolean checkPermissions() {
    int permissionState = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG);
    return permissionState == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (grantResults.length <= 0) {
            // If user interaction was interrupted, the permission request is cancelled and you
            // receive empty arrays.
            Log.i("Error", "User interaction was cancelled.");
        } else if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // Permission was granted. Kick off the process of building and connecting
            // GoogleApiClient.
            getCallDetails();
        } else {
        }
    }

}
```

}

and i hope you add below permission in android manifest file..

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG"/>
```

Comment: Using this it could only get the time after call is disconnected right? My aim to disconnect the call after 10 Min! SO how could i understand the users call time to disconnect after n min